# Select query to select another table based on the result it returns

Tags: mysql

At the moment I am running a simple select query i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM `form_expense`
```

One of the columns in this case titled '**value**' returns the following text **list_expense_category**. I would like to then look up all the values in the table **list_expense_category** and replace the value with all the results separated by a comma.

I know I am able to do this with an inner join if the value always references the same table but how would I go about this if the value could reference different tables. i.e.

Row 1 - value = list_expense_category

Row 2 - value = list_expense_projects

Row 3 - value = list_expense_currency

Comment: What did you try??

Comment: Table names can't be dynamic in sql queries. Is doing 2 queries where you build the second query programmatically from results of the first query an option? If not, it might be possible to do this with some sort of stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you @jussius for confirming that I can't have a dynamic sql query. I currently have two queries and get the required results programmatically. I was trying to simplify the API and seeing if I can use one SQL statement.